# correct way to use variables in the javascript DOM

Tags: javascript

What is the correct way to format the document.formToSubmit.submit() line?

```
    var formToSubmit = 'postcomment' + id;

    alert( ''+ formToSubmit +'' );

    document.formToSubmit.submit();
```

The formToSubmit variable seems to be correct but the submit() does not work.

Comment: Already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147265/javascript-using-variable-value-in-document-nameofformtosubmit-submit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put:

```
document.getElementById('postcomment' + id).submit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The formToSubmit is now a string not an object.
Try this:

```
 var formToSubmit = document.getElementById('postcomment' + id);
 alert( ''+ formToSubmit +'' );
 formToSubmit.submit();
```

Comment: well that returns a: [object HTMLFormElement] but still does not submit.

Comment: The formToSubmit contains the actual FORM object? You can check this with alert(formToSubmit.tagName). For a good (IE focussed) reference us this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533050(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Oh and of course what darin said: don't use document.formToSubmit but just formToSubmit.submit()

Answer (score 1):

Zyphrax is on the right track. You just need to remove "document." in the last line.

```
var formToSubmit = document.getElementById('postcomment' + id);
alert( ''+ formToSubmit +'' );
formToSubmit.submit();
```

The alert is working as expected since formToSubmit is now a DOM object and the message you're receiving is the appropriate string representation.  If you want to check that you have the right form you could do:

```
alert(formToSubmit.id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document['postcomment'+id].submit()
```

should also work